# How do we translate the Chinese slang “抠脚大汉” into English？

Tags: translation

And are there any proper ways to translate the action “抠脚”?

---

Update:

Thanks for your comments and answers. Although there is an "引经据典的"answer, 我本来是想知道它的字面意思。

Also, I tried Google translation which regrad 抠脚 as 抠出芯片的引脚。

Forgive my poor English...

Comment: So, what would you call a dirty man "who pretends to be a young beautiful lady on (and only on) the Internet and stealthily makes fun of netizens" in English?

Comment: Kou Jiao Da Han.

Comment: @Stan hmm the generic term would probably be troll? Someone who says things that are intended to cause disruption to readers, in effect annoying them to make fun of them. What do you think, fits? A dirty man who pretends to be a beautiful lady on the internet is probably ... just called a pervert? But if it's purely for a comical use, "joker" would suit better.

Comment: @Ming Yes they would be a subset of "troll", but there's still something subtle. And no, they're **not** physically or psychologically perverts ... maybe it's just difficult to say it in English.

Comment: Fine word. It'll be more interesting to find out who coined this phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Baidu baike:
网络语言，抠脚大汉即字面意思为抠脚的男人。事实上网络用语解释为：指一些猥琐男人在网络上扮女生，引围观，然后看着聊天记录一边抠脚一边大笑。

抠脚 : to scratch ones legs

抠脚大汉 ：Internet creep

Comment: According to Urban dictionary's definition for [Internet creep](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Internet%20Creep): "One who is incapable of chatting up girls in real life and therefore resorts to stalking them online." Thus, wrong, that's not 抠脚大汉.

Comment: Well can you say that they are not creeps on the internet?

Comment: Hmm, not that issue. Yes they're creeps but, the term 抠脚大汉 emphasizes something special ... It reminds me the trolling face in rage comics ... and at the same time, the term suggests their pretending to be girls on the Internet to make fun (this point is important).

Comment: I don't think that there is a specific term for this in English though...maybe we should try the English SE instead :D